# What is a good model for this data?(plot attached)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, modeling

[image]

I don't think a linear model would fit this? This is a change in the 'dependent' variable over trials in two conditions.
The hypothesis is that over trials the dependent variable reaches a tabletop/plateau. My model assumes a plateau. But how do I show that my data follows this?
Would you say that this is 'mostly' non-linear model?

Comment: You talk about a model that assumes a plateau. However you ask for a good model ?  Please clarify your question / problem. What do you actually want to know ?

Comment: If you want suggestions for a model that matches data, you need to show data (and explain what the data are). How large a sample size does your graph show?

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky in both conditions it's 30 people each. This what you see is my plotted data. My hypothesis is that the data over trails converge to a tabletop/plateau in both conditions. How do I test this hypothesis  for data converging to a tabletop.Plus the plotted data doesn't look like a linear model.

Comment: @Rodolphe I'm asking wrt to whether should I use a linear regression for this hypothesis testing?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Maybe try to think differently. Could you state formally the definition of what is a plateau ? Then how to see if your data becomes more like your definition, towards the last trials than at the beginning (maybe using a sliding window of trials)  ?

Comment: @Rodolphe Plateau here is like a tabletop(.that there is no variance over time)

Comment: Why do you make the plateau-hypothesis ? Is there some theory backing it up ? Because your data here doesn't look like it is going to plateau so this hypothesis must surely come from a preceding theory ?

Comment: @Rodolphe yes...The dependent variable can't reduce to zero. It increases over trials and comes back to a level above its usual activity level.Example, when a child is growing it reached maximum height during adulthood and as this person grows old, the height might reduce to that of being an adulthood, but it doesn't reduce back to that of a baby

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So when you talk about plateau you mean that period during which the dependent variable is at its highest before decreasing again ? Or the period after decreasing when it is back and stable at a higher than beginning value ?

Comment: Now that you have clarified a bit your assumptions / mental model, it is obviously not a linear relationship that your are looking for. Your model should include in some way the fact that you are hypothesising a plateau.     If you do not know what the equation of your model should look like, you should search the relevant expert litterature about it. Maybe  if that doesn't help try to construct it through first principles of your study-object i.e. process-based modeling and optimization.

Comment: @Rodolphe my data would. be something like an inverse gaussian dist.